# ¿Que hacer con preguntas a las que el autor no responde ni a los comentarios?

Tags: discusión

He visto que existen preguntas (*con o sin respuestas*) en las cuales el autor de la pregunta:

- No responde a los comentarios.
- No comenta las respuestas (*que obviamente tampoco no votó y/o aceptó*).
- Y (*en muy poco casos*) tampoco se ha vuelto a conectar desde que creo la pregunta.

Por tales razones, mi inquietudes son:

- ¿Que hacer ante este tipo de escenario?
- ¿Que debería suceder con la pregunta?
- ¿Esto afecta la graduación del sitio?